# Java: How to keep repeating a certain action until key is pressed again?

Tags: java

In my program, a number inside a matrix(2d array) moves around with key-control. When the user presses the space-bar(keycode 32, that's the number next to the case in my code), the code should fire a random-movement function and the function that repaints the GUI. Both are created and tested, both work. But, I just can't figure out how I can make the code keep repeating the random-movement function every second, until either the space-bar or another key is pressed.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Code-snippet(loop is a static boolean, whenever another key is pressed loop will be set to false. Still doesn't seem to work...):

```
case 32:
        loop = !loop;
        do{
            m.moveRandomly();
            updateMatrix(m);

        }while(loop);
        break;
```

Comment: Might be this thread is not looking at the latest value of `loop`. Have you tried declaring it as volatile? That way when the other thread modifies its value, it will be readable here as well.

Comment: If you are using the EDT, it would not catch the next key press. See [Swing concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You need to start a `Thread` and stop it when you want. That `Thread` will manage the move + update.

Comment: I don't see any reference about what you are talking. Are you using a console, AWT, Swing, SWT or Qt? Your code is no self-contained, minimal snippet. It will not compile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Create a global variable of a javax.swing.Timer, create an ActionListener in your main-function, create an instance of Timer aand start it. You can stop it with your KeyEvent when space (or any other key) is pressed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            m.moveRandomly();
            updateMatrix(m);
        }
    }
    javax.swing.Timer time = new Timer(1000, al);
    time.start();
}
```

Note: there are three classes in Java that have the name "Timer".

Comment: Yep, that was the next step of my answer but I write it before me. You should add `time.stop()` somewhere just to give the method to use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to work with to event in the same time.

First, the start action, that will loop indefinitly.

Second, the stop action, that should change a boolean to stop the first action.

Read the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You will learn that you are blocking the EDT (event dispatch thread) with your loop. Since this is the same thread that is catching the key, your are blocking yourself.

The idea here is to use a new thread to loop until your event is received.

Here is a simple example of your idea using a thread :

One button start the `Thread`, the other stop it setting the boolean to `false`. My thread will just append a `JTextArea` every 1/4s (This is note pretty, but this is the basic solution based on your original code)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getSource() == btnStart){
        t.start();
    } else if(arg0.getSource() == btnStop){
        t.stopAction();
    }
}

private class CounterThread extends Thread {

    private boolean b;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //activate the loop
        b = true;
        do{
            /* THE ACTION */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } while(b);
    }

    public void stopAction(){
        b = false;
    }
}
```

Swing provide a  [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class that do basicly the same thing, see [The_Programmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074012/4391450) for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {

static volatile boolean loop=false;

public static void main(String args[]){

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CollectionsDemo cd = new CollectionsDemo();
                cd.test();
            }
        }); 
        t.start();
    }

}


private static void test(){
    switch(32){
    case 32:
        loop = !loop;
        do{
            System.out.println("**");

        }while(loop);
        break;

    }
}
```

}

Your loop variable is not being set after it has been set first time(i.e while loop does not have end).above is working example you can do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new Thread in which you wait for the 
key events pressed by the user. Within the run method of the Runnable 
instance you implement your key loop. After a key is pressed you have to
use the `SwingUtilities.invokerLater` method which itself expects a Runnable instance to be implemented. Within its run method you invoke your `moveRandom` and `updateMatrics` methods. In this way the invocation of the draw methods are enqueued correctly at the end of the Swing Event and Dispatch queue. This has to be done to be drawn correctly.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
 {
  public void run() 
  {
    do
    {
      char key = System.in.read();
      switch (key)
      {
         // Wait for key events 
        case 32:
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
          public void run()
          {
             m.moveRandomly();
             updateMatrics();
          }
          break;
      }
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
    while (!stopped)
  }
});
thread.start();
```

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread